# Go to specific tab bar views

Tags: ios, xcode, view, controller

I have 6 view controllers when my app starts. It's like an image gallery. When a user pushes for example the button on the third view, he/she should gets to the third view in the tab bar.

I use this code to launch the view controllers on the top of the tab bar controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    static BOOL first = YES;
    if (first) {
        UIViewController *popup = [[Home1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home1ViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:popup animated:NO completion:nil];
        first = NO;
    }
}
```

By using this code to dismiss this new view, I'm just coming to the specific view, but not my tab-bar page...

```
-(IBAction)dismissView {
    TabBarPage3 *screen = [[ TabBarPage3 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
}
```

Please help me with this!
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to go to third view of UITabbar?? If it is, You can use [tabbar setSelectedIndex:index]; method

Comment: Ok, so I can use it like this? -(IBAction) {[tabbar setSelectedIndex:index]; };

Comment: yes. It worked with my project. [tabbarName setSelectedIndex:index]

Comment: Actually this might be better :) [((UITabBarController *)(self.parentViewController))setSelectedIndex:index]; just reach your parent view then cast to UITabBarController then use setSelectedIndex method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the code for change view on TabBar

```
[((UITabBarController *)(self.parentViewController))setSelectedIndex:index];
```

[Sample Project of UITabbar](http://www.gungorbasa.net/Media/Default/BlogPost/denemeUITabbar.zip)

Comment: Interesting. It worked for me. How did you push your first view of UITabBar?

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    static BOOL first = YES;
    if (first) {
        UIViewController *popup = [[Home1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home1ViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:popup animated:NO completion:nil];
        first = NO;
    }
}

Comment: I think the wrong part is you are directly open the view. Just create a tabbar and put it into as a first view. I wrote a sampleCode for you. I am going to upload somewhere on web and You can download and examine the code. Like I said you should directly create tabbar not first view

Comment: Were have you uploaded it?

Comment: there is a link on answer.click the "Sample Project of UITabbar" on post